# explode on empty string returns an array of length 1

Tags: php

Is there a split function in PHP that works similar to the JavaScript split()? For some reason explode() returns an array of length 1 when an empty string is given.

Example:

```
$aList = explode(",", "");    -> to return a 0-length array
$aList = explode(",", "1");   -> to return a 1-length array  $aList[0] = 1
$aList = explode(",", "1,5"); -> to return a 2-length array  $aList[0] = 1 and $aList[1] = 5
```

Comment: Try using `preg_split('~,~',$some_string,-1,PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY)` with the `PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY` flag. https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php

Comment: Any split or explode will return 1. Loigcally, thats all there is left. Cant "split" by what does not exists. So the return is the original value on set.

Comment: Thanks @bassxzero. That seems like it did the trick!

Answer (score 2):

I have two suggestion for you

**1. check empty string before explode**

```
if( strlen($str) ){
    $aList = explode(",", $str);
}
```

**2. use `empty` method to check array**

```
$aList = explode(",", $str);

if( empty($aList) ){}

if( !empty($aList) ){}
```

Comment: That seems like a lot of work when it comes to using $aList throughout the rest of the code.

Comment: yes ofcurse, but i dont know a better way

Comment: preg_split('~,~',$some_string,-1,PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY) looks uglier but does the trick. Thanks to @bassxzero

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is check the return value of "explode()":

> https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php
>
> If delimiter is an empty string (""), explode() will return FALSE.

PS:

Q: What's the rationale for "array of 1"?

> A string that doesn't contain the delimiter will simply return a
> one-length array of the original string (here, an "empty"string).

"GetSet" put it very well in his comment above:

> Any split or explode will return 1. Logically, that's all there is
> left.

Comment: The delimiter is not empty. The subject string can be empty

Comment: Dude - nobody said the delimiter wasn't empty.

Answer (score -1):

Please Try this one.

```
implode(",", $aList);
```

This is split function in PHP.
[str-split](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-split.php)
[spliti](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.spliti.php)

Comment: [implode()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.implode) does not split string